# Android, Vertical Alignment of Button in Linear Layout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a layout like the picture below, adaptive to screen size.
[image: AdaptiveLayout]

Here is the my XML Source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LnrLytRow1"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LnrLytRow2"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Here is what I got:
[image]

As it appears in the picture, the buttons are not aligned properly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_width` to `0dp` on all `Button`.

Comment: @Kevinrob I've already had it in my code!

Comment: `android:width` is not `android:layout_width`

Comment: @Kevinrob You're right. Sorry for my misunderstanding. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should switch to [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

It's designed to do exactly what you need. It's based on rows and columns and you can specify the row and col spans of elements. Not to mention that it will give you better performance then nesting `LinearLayout`s.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The issue that I have with GridLayout is that I can't fit the button in the layout properly. The right side of last column (buttons 4 and 7) exceed the boundaries of the GridLayout.

Comment: Make sure you are not setting width and height of the buttons. The `GridLayout` uses gravity settings to determine the dimensions of the views.

Answer (score 0):

You should change width of second LinearLayout and also remove android:width attribute from those buttons

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LnrLytRow1"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp">
    <Button
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/LnrLytRow2"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp">
    <Button
        android:text="Button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_weight="25" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle (any versions may be ok):

```
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+"
```

Copy this code in your xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:rowCount="2">

    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"/>

    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"/>

    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"/>

    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"/>

    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button5"/>
    <Button
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button6"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button7"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**SEE PROOF**

[image]